# what should be COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT in next-firebase-auth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use [next-firebase-auth](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth#setauthcookiesreq-res) package to manage authentication in my next js app. Before messing around, I wanted to run the example. However, I could not find proper explanation for the fields required in the .env file.

Could you please explain what should be the values of following fields in `local.env` file [here](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/tree/main/example)

- COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT
- COOKIE_SECRET_PREVIOUS
- NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY

The last one I guess is the `Web API key` shown on the config page. Not sure, please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @John

This question has official answer on GitHub [here](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/issues/178#issuecomment-842512978).

> `COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT` and `COOKIE_SECRET_PREVIOUS` could be any
> random strings (should be secret) to prevent client tampering.

Also I used the `Web API key` for `NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY` and it worked. When I used `yarn dev` it threw a lot of errors which I could not make sense of. However, when I run `yarn build && yarn start` it seems to work well.

Answer (score 3):

The next-fire-base-auth [config documentation](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth#config) links to the [cookies](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies) package. Under the [cookies example](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies#example), I found:

```
// Optionally define keys to sign cookie values
// to prevent client tampering
var keys = ['keyboard cat']
```

So I guess the keys can be anything. If that succeeds, I'll verify :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Probably  `COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT` and `COOKIE_SECRET_PREVIOUS` could be any random strings +10 for that. However, I am awaiting official answer from the team

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/issues/178

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example `env.local` (I've edited secrets and private keys, so this won't work for anyone, but I hope it helps):

```
FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099
COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT=zAHp6bFsN
COOKIE_SECRET_PREVIOUS=PvLc2f7nfc

# https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8099

FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL=firebase-adminsdk-yf9aj@next-firebase-e4999.iam.gserviceaccount.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY=AIzaSyBhl69VXT6TA5A7AheUELxlxFOXEN
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=next-firebase-e4999.firebaseapp.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://next-firebase-e4999-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=next-firebase-e4999

# Your Firebase private key.
# When using Vercel, add the private key with double quotes
# via the CLI, not the Vercel dashboard:
#   vercel secrets add firebase-private-key '"my-key-here"'
# Then, use `JSON.parse` in the app. See:
# https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/749#issuecomment-707515089
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY='"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQDRPKwLmBESII0E\n1J5Stmmj4OVr3Glp6m5iqp+/7lhC2niHPjlIeO++5YP+CkSZDmeA7XAIzuTUM1yW\nz+/CdwJBEbxVRHk7qg8W9oGbS+VlhyIIJPu7Ia6zLc2sLZ0UrBU4fAZeGpyXN+dR\ndm1rz/3kP8VzEwpOr1Kj0SPyWok+govZPhqK12e2huETPS42MqiZXR0YhVrhsR0Q\nZMDX58YKy1v71IRNotFKrDEUQx+/iexbIWG+qnSZKCRzofpRbNMCEutZMAZqKiM3\nYUZjWJXjpngfGJtBKu5GHXA+FbnDcNZpMBjc/ob5EoKkvUvvfh46gW0aq+T3MAtE\n1tm/Kv7JAgMBAAECggEAAXksK9zUFVgRe7zMoaq+rIo7BvcA7NKpQ5K7ukrkKBl3D7VRTTL+ZziaK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\ns0WOlUZu8BD+Zs0mC0kMB00=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"'

# Cookie options.
NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_SECURE=false # set to true in HTTPS environment
```